# Steps before updating privacy policy

Tags: privacy

What are the steps to be taken before changing/updating the privacy policy of an app or a service?
Such as informing the user etc.
Are there any strict rules to be followed?

Comment: Do you have any SOCII or III framework you are required to adhere to?

Comment: There is no framework as such

Comment: This is more of a legal question, which we are not equipped to handle. If your company has legal counsel, consult with them. If you do not, try [Law.Se]. :)